# Color axis labels by group

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes

I need to color the x-axis labels the same as the boxes. For example,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
df = matrix(rnorm(60),6,10)
rownames(df) = paste0(rep(c("A","B","C"),2),1:2)
df=melt(df)
df = cbind(df,grp=substr(df$Var1,1,1))
ggplot(df) + geom_boxplot(aes(x=Var1, y=value, fill=grp))
```

[image]

In the image above, I would like to color the x-axis labels of A1/A2 in red, B1/B2 in green and C1/C2 in blue. The following might work,

```
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour=c(rep("red",2), rep("green",2), rep("blue",2))))
```

[image]

But I have a **much larger dataset** which makes it harder to color manually. Would prefer a `colour=grp` type command. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a better way to do this, but since ggplot's `scale_fill_discrete` calls `scales::hue_pal`, you can use this to generate the same colors that your plot uses:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
df = matrix(rnorm(60),6,10)
rownames(df) = paste0(rep(c("A","B","C"),2),1:2)
df=melt(df)
df = cbind(df,grp=substr(df$Var1,1,1))
myplot <- ggplot(df) + geom_boxplot(aes(x=Var1, y=value, fill=grp))

library(scales)
x_cols <- rep(hue_pal()(length(unique(df$grp))), each=2)
myplot <- myplot + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour=x_cols)
```

The `x_cols` definition here creates a palette *function* with `hue_pal`, and then calls that function to generate a palette as long as the number of groups.  Using `rep` will work as long as the number of subgroups (A1, A2, etc.) are of equal length.  Maybe someone can extend this for a more general case.

Comment: Thanks! I generalized as follows: `x_cols = hue_pal()(length(levels(df$grp))); names(x_cols) = levels(df$grp); myplot + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour= x_cols[substr(levels(df$Var1),1,1)]))`

Comment: Note that `scale_fill/color_discrete` takes the same argument that `hue_pal` does, so you can make a common customized palette.